# Linkedin Company Statistics API is giving Wrong Geography Data

Tags: api, statistics, linkedin-api, country

Good Day...!

I am using linkedin API [ https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/123456/company-statistics?format=json ] to get company statistics including total count [ the total count was right ] with country-wise data.

The API gives wrong data when comparing with linked in admin dashboard records https://www.linkedin.com/company/123456/admin/analytics/followers/. Have attached the screenshots and response.

[Screenshot from linkedin API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wevQi.png)

[Response from Linkedin API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kFcs.png)

JSOn response:

```
  "count": 15118,
    "countries": {
      "_total": 96,
      "values": [
        {
          "entryKey": "in",
          "entryValue": "6664"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "sg",
          "entryValue": "648"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "cn",
          "entryValue": "223"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "ae",
          "entryValue": "217"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "us",
          "entryValue": "165"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "hk",
          "entryValue": "139"
        },
        {
          "entryKey": "th",
          "entryValue": "127"
        },
```

Comment: I guess that one result has a filter and the other one doesn't. Do the individual entries add up to the same number?

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks can you please suggest how to calculate the single entries . I just sharing the details with you [ Google text file ]https://drive.google.com/file/d/14OUpuEbsRS6Qgc3A6i4mGFCkliYogtd5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm just guessing here - it seems like you are running a query that filters the results (current year? current month?). I don't know what logic is behind your API call

Comment: There is no logic it is not monthly or anything it gives all data. Here i am using https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics there is no filter here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all, Who tried to answer me.

Below is the response from Linkedin Team.

The follower demographics is a solid number, but the targeted audience is a rounded number and this number is sanitized because it strips out any members that have made the choice not to be targeted